# Confused with direct initialization and copy initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I am confused with followed concepts:

```
string str="123";
```

Some books say that: using "=" is copy initialization,

but some articles say:  `string str="123"` is same as `string str("123")`. There is no doubt str("123") is directly initialization.

So which style for `string str="123";`?

How to judge which is copy initialization or directly initialization?

Comment: It all depends on your style of writing code.

Comment: See [copy initianization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).

Comment: you mean, use '=' is copy initial ?

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a matter of *grammar*:

- `T x = y;` is *copy-initialization*, and
- `T x(y);` is *direct-initialization*.

This is true for any type `T`. What happens exactly depends on what sort of type `T` is. For primitive types (e.g. `int`s), the two are exactly the same. For class-types (such as `std::string`), the two are practically the same, though copy-initialization requires that a copy-constructor be accessible and non-explicit (though it will not actually be called in practice).

Comment: is string str="123" related with copy constructor and be called copy initial?

Comment: @jiafu: The grammatical form is "copy initialization". It causes a call to some other, converting constructor, though, which takes a `char const *`. In principle, there could be *two* constructor calls, conversion followed by copying, but the second one is usually elided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is called copy initialization.

Instead of default constructing str and then constructing another `string` from `"123"` using `string(const char*)` and then assigning the two strings,  the compiler just construct a string using string(const char*) with "123".

> `string str="123"` is same as `string str("123")`. There is no doubt
>   str("123") is directly initial

**However remember that is possible only if the corresponding constructor is not [*explicit*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/explicit-ctors.html).**

Comment: is string str="123" related with copy constructor and be called copy initial?

Comment: @jiafu - Yes, it is "related" to the copy constructor, as there formally is a copy involved, but the compiler will optimize that out. If you have a user defined class with constructors that are `explicit`, `private`, or `delete`'ed, you might notice a difference. For `std::string` that is not the case.

Comment: @jiafu You can get a more detailed info on the link I have provided it covers when and how copy initialization is used.